# Mapping geometric to electric parameters for a PMSM machine

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, design, electric-machine, modeling

I am looking at a [PMSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor#Permanent-magnet_motors) machine described by the following equations:

$$\frac{di_d}{dt} = \frac{\omega_e L_q}{L_d}i_q - \frac{R_s}{L_d}i_d + \frac{u_d}{L_d}$$
$$\frac{di_q}{dt} = -\frac{\omega_e (i_dL_d + \Psi_m)}{L_q}i_q - \frac{R_s}{L_q}i_q + \frac{u_q}{L_q}$$
$$\frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{\frac{3p}{2}((L_d-L_q)i_d + \Psi_m)i_q - T_L - \beta \omega_m}{J}$$

where \$ \omega_e\$ is the electrical speed, related to the rotor speed as \$\omega_e=p\omega_m\$. \$p\$ denotes the number of pole pairs. \$u_d\$ and \$u_q\$ are the stator voltages in the d-q frame and \$i_d\$ and \$i_q\$ are the currents. \$T_L\$ is the load torque. \$L_d\$ and \$L_q\$ are the stator d-axis and q-axis inductance. \$R_s\$ is the equivalent resistance of each stator winding. \$\Psi_m\$ is the permanent magnet flux linkage. \$J\$ is the moment of inertia of the rotor. \$\beta\$ is the viscous damping coefficient.

I was wondering if there is any method to map geometric parameters like: air gap, shaft diameter, tooth width etc. to parameters like: resistance, inductance, flux etc. with analytical equations? I have read about magnetic equivalent circuits but whenever I dig deeper in the literature I find that people use [FEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) methods to obtain those parameters. Are there approximation methods, so I could a) Define geometric parameters for my machine; b) Link geometric parameters to electric parameters; c) To model my system as in the described differential equations above? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I fear this isn't *standard fare*. And you are likely on your own. I think it would make a great master's thesis, though. And yes, numerical approximation (FEM/FEA, etc.) are appropriate tools ***if*** you can create the necessary partial differentials needed. And you cannot just punch those out, blindly. But given a good understanding of how FEM works and what it needs to get you answers that will matter to you and a good understanding of your own problem, I'm sure things can be paired up to give reasonable answers. I just doubt anyone here has the cheat-sheet for this.